# How to append a new row in Python (BeaufitulSoup) in a CSV for a multi-url scraper?

Tags: python, csv, beautifulsoup

I am pretty new to Python and I am testing my first scraper (using some codes I found here and there). I was able to write the CSV with all the info needed, but now I am trying to input more than 1 URL and the script is just writing the last URL I insert in the array, it's like is not appending new URLs but just re-writing on the same first raw.

I looked everywhere and tried a lot of things, but I think I need some help, thanks!

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from csv import writer

urls = ['https://example.com/1', 'https://example.com/2']

for url in urls:
    my_url = requests.get(url)
    html = my_url.content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')

    info = []

print (urls)

lists = soup.find_all('div', class_="profile-info-holder")
links = soup.find_all('a', class_="intercept")

with open('multi.csv', 'w', encoding='utf8', newline='') as f:
    thewriter = writer(f)
    header = ['Name', 'Location', 'Link', 'Link2', 'Link3']
    thewriter.writerow(header)

    for list in lists:
        name = list.find('div', class_="profile-name").text
        location = list.find('div', class_="profile-location").text

        social1 = links[0]
        social2 = links[1]
        social3 = links[2]

        info = [name, location, social1.get('href'),social2.get('href'),social3.get('href')]
        thewriter.writerow(info)
```

Comment: Seems like you iterate through all urls in a loop, but just keep overriding the variable `soup`, then use the last value of iteration in the next pieces of code after the first for loop.

Comment: Thank you @mohkamfer - any idea how can I do that?

Comment: You can either do all the scraping you need in the for loop, or what I prefer is aggregating responses in a list first, then operate on them in another loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Basic approach

- Open the file in append mode (‘a’).
- Write cursor points to the end of file.
- Append ‘\n’ at the end of the file using write() function
- Append the given line to the file using write() function.
- Close the file.

--

```
with open('multi.csv', 'a', encoding='utf8', newline='') as f:
```

You may have to arange your loops in another way, but without `urls` it is hard to describe:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from csv import writer

urls = ['https://example.com/1', 'https://example.com/2']


with open('multi.csv', 'a', encoding='utf8', newline='') as f:
    thewriter = writer(f)
    header = ['Name', 'Location', 'Link', 'Link2', 'Link3']
    thewriter.writerow(header)

    
    for url in urls:
        my_url = requests.get(url)
        html = my_url.content
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')

        info = []

        lists = soup.find_all('div', class_="profile-info-holder")
        
        for l in lists:
            name = l.find('div', class_="profile-name").text
            location = l.find('div', class_="profile-location").text
            links = l.find_all('a', class_="intercept")
            social1 = links[0]
            social2 = links[1]
            social3 = links[2]

            info = [name, location, social1.get('href'),social2.get('href'),social3.get('href')]
            thewriter.writerow(info)
```

Comment: thanks, I tried this but when I run it, it just adds again the same URL (n1) twice, so I think my problem is about the for loop or something like that. I just need to have 1 URL output per row - any idea how? Thanks

Comment: thank you @hedgehog, I tried this at the end of the file:
f.write('\n')
        f.close()

but nothing changed, just the same URL again

Comment: could you post the two urls, so that i can reproduce the behavior. please.

Comment: thank you so much!!! it does work now :) the only thing I miss now is how to avoid out of range index social2 = links[1] when one of the URLs doesn't have more than 1 link, but this is something else to fix. Again, thanks so much! @HedgeHog

Comment: hey there again! @hedgehog I wanted to ask you if you have any idea why sometimes the loop break showing this error message:    re.search(r"https?://([^/]+)", l["href"]).group(1): l["href"]
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

Comment: @alexeidos: Seems that your pattern wont be found - This would be predestined to [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) with some more details.